# Mongoose casting array to string when using $set

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have my model:

```
var QuestionSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    question: String,
    answers: [String],
    set_id: String
});
```

And I update like so:

```
questionModel.update({
    _id: id
}, {
    $set: {
        title: req.body.title,
        question: req.body.question,
        answers: req.body.answers
    }
}, function (err, numAffected) {

});
```

I've checked `req.body.answers` and it is an array, however, it seems to get saved in the DB as `foo,bar`, as in, a string, not an array!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
answers: req.body.answers[0]
```

Was the eventual workaround, no idea why!? If anyone can shed any light on why it was coming from a form with inputs: `name="answers[]"` being passed as `[[foo, bar]]`...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that because you've used '[String]' instead of 'Array' in your schema definition, then when you go to update the model, the array is cast to a string, rather than being saved as an array. Try the below:

```
var QuestionSchema = new Schema({
   title: String,
   question: String,
   answers: Array,
   set_id: String
});
```

It also looks like you would only use brackets around a schema type where you are defining meta properties:

```
var animalSchema = new Schema({
   name: String,
   type: String,
   tags: { type: [String], index: true } // field level
});
```